# Linq Projecting from one type to a second using fluent syntax

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a EF table/object that I want to map into a new object that is virtually identical. 
I could use AutoMapper but was hoping to do it with Linq projection.
I am using this code to create a list of the objects.

```
var ci = db.Incidents
    .Where(a => a.FollowUpDate.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
        && a.FollowUpDate.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
    .ToList();
```

What I am having problems understanding how I use projection to convert/map Incidents to IncidentsView?

Comment: Something like: `.Select(r=> new YourObject { Property1 = r.Property 1,.....})` ??

Comment: I remember recently trying to do something like this.  I got around it by creating a second list (SecondList), then iterating what you would have as the "ci" list and doing like SecondList.Add(new NewItem { Property = i.Property }), etc.  Probably not the most efficient but it worked for my case.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Habib Make it an answer so I can accept. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can project your results from the query to your class object. Suppose your class name is `MyClass` then you can do:

```
var ci = db.Incidents
    .Where(a => a.FollowUpDate.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
               && a.FollowUpDate.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
    .Select(r=> new MyClass
          { 
            Property1 = r.Property1,
           //rest of the properties .....
         }).ToList();
```